# Control Volume problem, valve with variable area

Tags: thermodynamics

Under ordinary operation a steady flow of helium gas of 40 g/s passes from a large storage manifold through an expansion engine as shown in Figure. There are certain times when the engine must be shut down for short intervals, but not the inlet flow rate, however, flow rate can be decreased at such times and thus helium stream must be diverted. It is proposed to employ adjacent system that consists a large insulated tank (tank C) of 3 m3 capacity with a safety valve venting to the atmosphere through the plant ducting system.
The emergency diverting system is operated in the following manner. If the expansion engine must be shut down (or operates improperly), valve B is shut and A is opened, letting helium into tank. When the pressure in C raises to 3.0 bar, safety valve D operates, venting gas. Initially tank C is evacuated to very low pressures. We shall assume that when gas enters in this tank, it is well mixed but has negligible heat transfer with the tank walls. Assume that helium is an ideal gas with a constant heat capacity

(a)If the safety valve on tank C should operate, we would like to maintain a constant mass of gas in this tank equal to the mass at the time the safety tripped. The mass flow rate into the tank is, as noted above, 40 g/s, the flow rate from the safety valve is expressed as, ṁ(g/s)= K A P/T
Where, K is a constant, A is the throat area of the valve, P and T are pressure and temperature in tank C. To keep the tank mass constant, the valve flow area A will be varied.
What are the pressure and temperature of the tank C 10 s after the safety valve opens? Write the suitable final energy equation for this process. Write the expression for Area “A “to keep the mass of the tank C constant and find change in A with time.

(b)Find the total entropy change of the gas entering in tank, tank, gas leaving to surroundings, and the universe during the time between the opening of the valve D and a time 10 s later. Write a suitable equation for finding entropy change for the above mentioned cases. The vented gas mixes with an infinite amount of air exterior to the tank and cools to 300 K and 1 bar. Assume the entropy change of mixing is negligible.

I couldn't get an idea to find the area expression. Please help.
[image: the image related to the problem is shown below]

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: I couldn't get any idea how to proceed,as I havent solved any problem of this type before. I tried googling and didnt get any clue. I don't need the whole solution, I just need a hint regarding how to approach.